# Facetime HD Camera undetected in Vodburner

Tags: macos, facetime

I have installed Vodburner but it is not detecting the Facetime HD camera. Please suggest how to solve this.

Comment: Just downloaded and installed Vodburner myself — camera not detected either. Seems like a bug.